# vs code sidebar tree folder structure not working

Tags: javascript, windows, visual-studio-code

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5v1yS.png)

When I try to create a folder within another folder (a normal tree)on the sidebar, instead of branching below the folder, the new one appears on the side, like so:
“Folder A\Folder B”
What I want is for it to be in this structure:

->Folder A

------>Folder B

How can fix it?

Comment: Does FolderA contains anything except FolderB?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In your settings either uncheck "Explorer: Compact Folders" or in your settings JSON set the value for `explorer.compactFolders` to `false`.

This feature was introduced in version 1.41. [Changelog](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_41#_compact-folders-in-explorer)

Comment: thank you! what a strange feature